# opencv (emgucv) not working in unity in osx?

Tags: unity-game-engine, osx-yosemite, emgucv, opencv3.0

i am at the point, where i just would want to know if **anybody out there has emguCV.unity running inside unity in osx?**

there are many tips concerning DllNotFoundExceptions and unity. all of them do not work in my case. i spent allmost four days searching and trying out everything.

the exact error is:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrInvoke ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Emgu.CV.CvInvoke ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Assets/Plugins/emgucv.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:cvRedirectError (Emgu.CV.CvInvoke/CvErrorCallback,intptr,intptr)
>     at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x001f7] in /Users/Lev/Documents/workspace/Text_Scanner/Assets/Emgu.CV/Emgu.CV/PInvoke/CvInvoke.cs:353 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrInvoke..cctor () [0x00006] in /Users/Lev/Documents/workspace/Text_Scanner/Assets/Emgu.CV/Emgu.CV.OCR/OcrInvoke.cs:26 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract..ctor () [0x00011] in /Users/Lev/Documents/workspace/Text_Scanner/Assets/Emgu.CV/Emgu.CV.OCR/Tesseract.cs:45

(there is the emgucv.bundle in Assets/Plugins/ with the libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib inside at the correct position. i copied the dylibs and the whole bundle to alle possible positions. including the project folder, unity-editor folder, ...)

there is no compilition error. the error happens after starting play in editor and in standallone mac as well.
i built emgucv with the cmake settings in emgucv.unity from emgucv 3.0.0.

(i even tried opencvsharp did not work neither)

i am desperate. please help me or just tell me, there is no way. 
thanks in advance,
lev

Answer (score 0):

It works!

this is, how i got it to work:

1. do as instructed here until the cmake command (don't do the cmake)
   http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#OSX
2. instead do:

   1. cd platforms/osx/
   2. ./configure_universal
   3. ./makeBundle
   4. cd ../../Emgu.CV.Unity/
   5. ./copy_unity_assets
   6. ./copy_demo_assets
3. then copy the folder Emgu.CV.Unity to your workspace and
4. open it with unity as a project.

that was it for me :-)

cheers,
lev